# Expected Expression for unsubscribe()

Tags: angular, typescript

```
ERROR in src/app/spotify-token.service.ts:53:19 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

53     this.tokenSub?.unsubscribe();
                     ~
src/app/spotify-token.service.ts:53:33 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

53     this.tokenSub?.unsubscribe();
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpotifyTokenService implements OnDestroy {

  private clientID = environment.clientID;
  private clientSecret = environment.clientSecret;

  private accessToken: string;
  private accessTokenExpires: Date;
  private tokenSub: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private getAccessToken(): Observable<any> {

    return new Observable((o) => {
      let auth = btoa(`${this.clientID}:${this.clientSecret}`);
      const authBody = new HttpParams().set('grant_type', 'client_credentials');

      this.tokenSub = this.http.post<any>("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", authBody.toString(), 
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': `Basic ${auth}` } }).subscribe(token => {
        this.accessToken = token.access_token;
        this.accessTokenExpires = new Date();
        this.accessTokenExpires.setSeconds(this.accessTokenExpires.getSeconds() + token.expires_in);
        o.next(this.accessToken)
      });
    });
  }

  getBearerToken(): Observable<any> {

    if (!this.accessToken) { 
      // no access token, so get a fresh one
      return this.getAccessToken();
    } else { 
      if (new Date() < this.accessTokenExpires) { 
        // access token exists and is valid, so return it
        return new Observable(o => o.next(this.accessToken));
      } else { 
        // access token exists, but is no longer valid, so get a fresh one
        return this.getAccessToken(); 
      }
    }
  }
  ngOnDestroy():void{
    this.tokenSub?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Which typescript version are you using? Check your package.json for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Subscription` of `rxjs`.

**Import:**

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
```

**Change:**

```
private tokenSub: Subscription = new Subscription();


ngOnDestroy():void{
    this.tokenSub.unsubscribe();
}
```